# I am getting issues with vtiger the open source crm, was working fine but now when i try to configure mailbox it loads foever doesnt work

Tags: php, content-management-system, crm, vtiger

I am getting issues with vtiger the open source CRM, was working fine but now when i try to configure mailbox it loads forever doesn't work.

I have allowed some debugging and getting these errors

> Warning: Undefined array key "/home/bus8yrg08ns7/public_html/includes/../languages/en_us/MailManager.php" in /home/bus8yrg08ns7/public_html/includes/runtime/LanguageHandler.php on line 135

> Warning: Undefined array key "/home/bus8yrg08ns7/public_html/includes/../languages/custom/en_us/MailManager.php" in /home/bus8yrg08ns7/public_html/includes/runtime/LanguageHandler.php on line 150

> Warning: Undefined array key "/home/bus8yrg08ns7/public_html/includes/../languages/en_us/Vtiger.php" in /home/bus8yrg08ns7/public_html/includes/runtime/LanguageHandler.php on line 135

> Warning: Undefined array key "/home/bus8yrg08ns7/public_html/includes/../languages/custom/en_us/Vtiger.php" in /home/bus8yrg08ns7/public_html/includes/runtime/LanguageHandler.php on line 150

> Warning: Undefined array key 29 in /home/bus8yrg08ns7/public_html/include/utils/UserInfoUtil.php on line 2170

> Warning: Undefined array key 29 in /home/bus8yrg08ns7/public_html/include/utils/UserInfoUtil.php on line 2170

> Warning: Undefined array key 29 in /home/bus8yrg08ns7/public_html/modules/Users/models/Privileges.php on line 70

> Warning: Undefined array key 29 in /home/bus8yrg08ns7/public_html/modules/Users/models/Privileges.php on line 70

> Warning: Undefined array key 29 in /home/bus8yrg08ns7/public_html/include/utils/UserInfoUtil.php on line 2170

i have tried deleting a load of documents and dead leads and this infect did solve another problem that was happening, the history of the CRM had a deleted error in my widgets. and then returned back to normal when i emptied my recycling bin. weather these are related i have no idea. the only thing i have done in between this working and not is add and delete users and configure their mailboxes